# Terminal not running after change command

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I tried to costumize my terminal from Edit>Profile Prefences>Title and Command. I check the Run a custom command instead of my shell and i think i write wrong command so the terminal won't run anymore. I have try reinstall the terminal from Software Center, search on google, but not solving.

How to return my terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:

Are you able to at least open the terminal application? If so, you should be able to re-open the terminal's preferences and disable the "Run a custom command." What happens if you open the terminal? Do you get an error message?

Option 2:

The simple solution to this problem, would be to reset the terminal application's preferences and profiles. You can do this by pressing `CTRL` + `ALT` + `F1` ... Once you have done this enter your username and your password at prompt. Then, once you see the shell, enter **`gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/gnome-terminal`** (And press enter).